# Is it worth modding an external audio jack to a camcorder?

Tags: adc, microphone, sound, electret

I have a good HD camcorder that records low fidelity audio.

Instead of buying a new camcorder, I am tempted to try some external microphones on it, because the electret microphone wires are only 2 leads.

Is there a chance i'll still have low quality sound afterwards, because the microphone circuits are noisy and low quality?

Comment: A lot of unknowns. At the very least I'd expect a more complicated circuit than a simple external wire connection. The internal amplifier, filters, and ADC are all designed for the specs of that existing microphone.

Comment: Consider using an independent high quality stereo audio recording device and editing the sound and video together later using various media software.

Comment: Also, assuming this is a digital recording device, beyond the electrical aspects we have no idea how the camcorder is handling the audio encoding.  For all we know it may compress the audio many times more then the "usual" mp3 settings (about 1/10 the original uncompressed CD data rate) possibly resulting in poor quality audio no matter what the source may be.

Comment: @st2000 and that... is what clappers are for :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say the most likely cause of the LoFi audio is the data compression of the audio to get it small, or alternately the AD conversion, possibly the acoustic properties of where the mic is housed.

If you like the look of the footage and want to capture better audio I would recommend using an external recorder like a Zoom H1, or even just a phone that you have, and sync the audio and video in post

Comment: It's an ex expensive panasonic, and indeed the AD conversion is noisy, it's around 70-80dB signal to noise ratio. I just cut into the plastic housing around the mic and tried out two different mics, there are less tinny sounding but equally noisy. i found a video editor with advanced noise reduction which can probably help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2H2_1wrfAg

Comment: Where have you got the 70-80dB figure from? 

I would say that the majority of the noise is coming from the circuitry after the microphone, so unless you're willing to gut that out, and replace/shield everything you may just have to deal with it.

Be careful with noise reduction - it doesn't just affect the noise, it will have an impact on the audio that you want. In my opinion having some noise there is better than being able to notice the noise floor moving about

Comment: Is this digital audio?  Or is this analog audio?  Usually compression does not have a S/N problem, but a quality of content problem.  Nothing against your Panasonic, but even my low end DLSR runs rings around my 8mm digital tape camcorder.  Both in video quality and sound fidelity.  Hands down.  Not even close.

Comment: 70-80 is just a guess from doing some years of audio engineering, i used to check mic SNR all the time. I don't have precise volume display here and i think that the ambient noise is about -75dB roundabout. It's a very good idea to shield some of the circuitry going into the AD, but it's probably too difficult. at -75db, a noise reduction function that uses a sample of the noise has generally amazing results and can get the noise signal to 90dB at least with good audio.